# sending data from controller to view not working

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send data from controller to view but it gives error that variable is not defined. can any one tell me what is the problem?

here is my code in controller.

```
$data['num']=1;
$data['message']="Invalid email address or password.";   
$this->load->view('admin/Login',$data);
```

this is view

```
<?php echo $message;?>
```

Comment: its a correct way, but what is exactly error which you getting?

Comment: Are you sure that the correct controller method is handling the view for you currently? Seems to me that another controller method might load your view so variable will not get defined. But please post more code.

Comment: i m totally mad. i was doing  echo that statement in wrong view :-D